# Php, expects at most parameters for methods too

Tags: php

this code snippet:

```
unlink ('C:\dfdf.dfg', 1, 2, 3);
```

will breakdown, saying this function cant accept more than 2 parameters (it wouldnt cause problems but it enforces us to be precise).
But what about methods?

```
class C
{
    public function b ($a)
    {
    }
}

$c = new C();
$c->b(1,2);
```

`b()` gets one more unnecessary parameter, and not even a notice generates

Comment: See function_get_args : http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php if you want to overload your method in this way,

Comment: It's up to your own code to check for additional arguments and throw an exception if you need it to.... there are valid use cases where you may choose only to include $a in the function/method definition, but allow other arguments to be passed in (the use of variadics in PHP 5.6 makes this even more fun); so PHP itself should not give any notice or warning in this case

Comment: @CD001 I dont want to overload I just want to be noticed if I set more parameters than it needs

Comment: In which case you *are* overloading the method - you'll need to tell it to spaff out an error or throw an Exception if that occurs, @MarkBaker is bang on the money with his comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Your method *could* be using `func_get_args` to accept any variable number of parameters. Therefore PHP isn't going to complain. In the C implementation for `unlink`, PHP is explicitly validating the incoming parameters and throws an error if necessary. You'd have to replicate that yourself:

```
function b($a) {
    if (count(func_get_args()) > 1) {
        trigger_error('b() does not accept more than 1 parameter', E_USER_NOTICE);
    }
    ..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies if you see the SOURCE CODE of php built in function,

```
PHP_FUNCTION(unlink)
{
char *filename;
size_t filename_len;
php_stream_wrapper *wrapper;
zval *zcontext = NULL;
php_stream_context *context = NULL;
if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS(), "p|r", &filename, &filename_len, &zcontext) == FAILURE) {
RETURN_FALSE;
}
context = php_stream_context_from_zval(zcontext, 0);
wrapper = php_stream_locate_url_wrapper(filename, NULL, 0);
if (!wrapper || !wrapper->wops) {
php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "Unable to locate stream wrapper");
RETURN_FALSE;
}
if (!wrapper->wops->unlink) {
php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "%s does not allow unlinking", wrapper->wops->label ? wrapper->wops->label : "Wrapper");
RETURN_FALSE;
}
RETURN_BOOL(wrapper->wops->unlink(wrapper, filename, REPORT_ERRORS, context));
}
```

now , look carefully at this piece of code , because of this it throws error

```
if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS(), "p|r", &filename, &filename_len, &zcontext) == FAILURE) {
RETURN_FALSE;
}
```

Where in your class you are **NOT** validating number of `arguments` passed to it, you can use `try, catch` block here , to restrict the number of arguments passed to your class method. I hope that cleared your doubt.

[**REFERENCE**](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/file.c)